# When checkbox is checked it triggers more events

Tags: php, html

I am making an application that adds a name and some text to a database depending on what checkbox is pressed.
I have an if statement that triggers when both checkboxes have been pressed. The problem is that everytime you select both, it adds text for the first checkbox, the second one, and then combined. I want so that if you press both, show only the combined text.
This is the code that has issues.

```
      {
        if (isset($_POST['laptopCheck'])) {
          $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=liamed", "root", "");
          $nume = $_POST['nume'];
          $prenume = $_POST['prenume'];
          $obiecte = 'laptop';
          $q = "insert into users(nume,prenume,inventar)values(:nume,:prenume,:obiecte)";
          $r = $pdo->prepare($q);
          $r->execute(array(":nume"=>$nume, ":prenume"=>$prenume, ":obiecte"=>$obiecte));
        }
        if (isset($_POST['telefonCheck'])) {
          $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=liamed", "root", "");
          $nume = $_POST['nume'];
          $prenume = $_POST['prenume'];
          $obiecte = 'telefon';
          $q = "insert into users(nume,prenume,inventar)values(:nume,:prenume,:obiecte)";
          $r = $pdo->prepare($q);
          $r->execute(array(":nume"=>$nume, ":prenume"=>$prenume, ":obiecte"=>$obiecte));
        }
        if (isset($_POST['telefonCheck']) && isset($_POST['laptopCheck'])) {
          $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=liamed", "root", "");
          $nume = $_POST['nume'];
          $prenume = $_POST['prenume'];
          $obiecte = 'laptop si telefon';
          $q = "insert into users(nume,prenume,inventar)values(:nume,:prenume,:obiecte)";
          $r = $pdo->prepare($q);
          $r->execute(array(":nume"=>$nume, ":prenume"=>$prenume, ":obiecte"=>$obiecte));
        }
      }
```

**This is my whole code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="nume" placeholder="nume" required>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="prenume" placeholder="prenume" required>
      <br>
      Laptop: <input type="checkbox" name="laptopCheck">
      <br>
      Telefon: <input type="checkbox" name="telefonCheck">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Adauga in baza de date">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </form>
    <table border="1px">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nume</th>
        <th>Prenume</th>
        <th>Obiecte</th>
      </tr>
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['sub']))
      {
        if (isset($_POST['laptopCheck'])) {
          $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=liamed", "root", "");
          $nume = $_POST['nume'];
          $prenume = $_POST['prenume'];
          $obiecte = 'laptop';
          $q = "insert into users(nume,prenume,inventar)values(:nume,:prenume,:obiecte)";
          $r = $pdo->prepare($q);
          $r->execute(array(":nume"=>$nume, ":prenume"=>$prenume, ":obiecte"=>$obiecte));
        }
        if (isset($_POST['telefonCheck'])) {
          $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=liamed", "root", "");
          $nume = $_POST['nume'];
          $prenume = $_POST['prenume'];
          $obiecte = 'telefon';
          $q = "insert into users(nume,prenume,inventar)values(:nume,:prenume,:obiecte)";
          $r = $pdo->prepare($q);
          $r->execute(array(":nume"=>$nume, ":prenume"=>$prenume, ":obiecte"=>$obiecte));
        }
        if (isset($_POST['telefonCheck']) && isset($_POST['laptopCheck'])) {
          $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=liamed", "root", "");
          $nume = $_POST['nume'];
          $prenume = $_POST['prenume'];
          $obiecte = 'laptop si telefon';
          $q = "insert into users(nume,prenume,inventar)values(:nume,:prenume,:obiecte)";
          $r = $pdo->prepare($q);
          $r->execute(array(":nume"=>$nume, ":prenume"=>$prenume, ":obiecte"=>$obiecte));
        }
      }
      $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=liamed", "root", "");
      $query = "select * from liamed.users";
      $d = $pdo->query($query);
      foreach ($d as $data){

    ?>

    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $data['id'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['nume'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['prenume'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['inventar'];?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php }
  ?>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: You want to do ~ `if (telefoneCheck && laptopCheck) { ... } else if (telefoneCheck) { ... } else if (laptopCheck) { ... }`. Right now it's entering all 3 conditionals when `telefoneCheck` and `laptopCheck` are true because they're 3 separate `if` statements. If you change it to an `else if` then it will only execute code in one of the sections. Also you'll want to move the `phone && laptop` check to the first one, otherwise it will prematurely enter into another section because `if (phone)` is true when `phone && laptop` are both set.

Comment: what @WOUNDEDStevenJones said, just with `elseif` not `else if`

Comment: @AlexBarker https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php you can write it as `elseif` or `else if` - both are valid and identical in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just alter the order which you check the values and use an elseif

You can also remove a fair bit of repeated code.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=liamed", "root", "");

$q = "insert into users
              (nume,prenume,inventar)
        values(:nume,:prenume,:obiecte)";
$r = $pdo->prepare($q);

$obiecte = false;

if (isset($_POST['telefonCheck']) && isset($_POST['laptopCheck'])) {
    $obiecte = 'laptop si telefon';
} elseif (isset($_POST['laptopCheck'])) {
    $obiecte = 'laptop';
} elseif (isset($_POST['telefonCheck'])) {
    $obiecte = 'telefon';
}

if ( $obiecte ) {  // only run if one of the above if's changed this from false
    $r->execute(array(":nume" => $_POST['nume'], 
                      ":prenume" => $_POST['prenume'], 
                      ":obiecte"=>$obiecte)
                );
}
```

Comment: slight warning with this - if both `telefonCheck` and `laptopCheck` aren't submitted, it will still try to insert a row, which is slightly different logic than what is in the question. It would be safer to first set `$obiecte = ''` and then before executing the query, check `if ($obiecte !== '') { $r->execute(...); }`. But +1 for simplifying the code

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Good point, well made. Fixed that I think